# Xamarin form bluetooth keyboard input in entry slow

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, bluetooth

I am using xamarin form targeting UWP and I have a bluetooth scanner that I use to input in an entry field. When I am scanning the barcode scanner in the entry, it is inserting slowly in the entry and sometimes stop after 4 characters where I have to put the focus on it so that it continues inserting. Does anyone has any recommandations on how I can make it faster. Thank you.

Comment: We need to see your implementation to help you more

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue that input characters with bluetooth keyboard, have you tried to check  is there other bluetooth device interference?

Comment: It was an issue linked to the device.We change to another model. Thanks